# DataTables - Requested unknown parameter (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatables

Ive got a problem with DataTables, because it doesn`t read my Json data. It says:

> DataTables warning: table id=exerciseTable - Requested unknown parameter 'ExerciseId' for row 0, column 0.

After this error it makes 2 lines with empty data (so it knows that there are 2 records in this table). I found many threads similar to mine, but nothing helps. Do you know what`s wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllDataApiJson()
{
    var data = DbContext.Exercises.ToList();
            
    return new JsonResult(data);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Exercise
{
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    [DataType("varbinary(max)")]
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
    <table id="exerciseTable" class="table table-striped border">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#exerciseTable").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                "url": "/Admin/GetAllDataApiJson",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            columns: [
                { "data": 'ExerciseId' },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Desc" },
                { "data": "Photo" },
                {
                    "data": "id",
                    "width": "20%",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return `<div class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-success' href='/admin/edit?id=${data}'>Edytuj</a> &nbsp; <a onclick=delete('admin/deletebydataapijson?id='+${data}) class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor: pointer'>Usuń</a></div>`
                    }
                }
            ],
            "width": "100%"    
        });
    });
```

**Brakepoint with Json data:**
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSLZ4.png)

**DataTable after error:**
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLekr.png)

Comment: Can you show us the JSON that is actually being returned (not the object that is being serialized to JSON)

Comment: It look like this:
"[{\"ExerciseId\":4,\"Name\":\"rerererer\",\"Desc\":null,\"Photo\":null},{\"ExerciseId\":5,\"Name\":\"adaaadadadada\",\"Desc\":\"opis opis\",\"Photo\":null},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name should be lowercase:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#exerciseTable").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            "url": "/Admin/GetAllDataApiJson",
            "dataSrc": "",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": 'exerciseId' },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "desc" },
            { "data": "photo" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "width": "20%",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-success' href='/admin/edit?id=${data}'>Edytuj</a> &nbsp; <a onclick=delete('admin/deletebydataapijson?id='+${data}) class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor: pointer'>Usuń</a></div>`
                }
            }
        ],
        "width": "100%"    
    });
});
```

Result:

[image]